# Is it possible to store the values of Array as one new variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have sample data in database with multiple different name,date and menu... I need to proceed data with the same name and date, but each data has a different menu...

DATABASE

[image]

the problem is that I need to store all the menu from the same name and date as a new variable since I need to call it for table view in web, and the table need to be look like this :

TABLE

[image]

I already using array to store the data menu for each same name and date, so the menu come out like this :

[image]

I'm really confused at how to continue make approach after this part,

How do I get output --> Candy Cake Cheese , so I can call it in table (?)

I think I can't seem to just use concat_ws in my query, since the values are from the same field of array, or is there another solution so I can get the output table I need ??
Thanks :)

Comment: Which type of output you needed please explain clearly

Comment: @NathanSrivi I'm sorry... I need the output in a single variable.. is that possible ?

Comment: Please, tell which database are you using. It's relevant to the question. :)

Comment: @PauloFreitas Hmm.. I think already give the sample database table above..  O.o
It's from a table in database... 
Ohh...MySQL database... is that what u mean ? It's MYSQL... sorry for not wrote it down :)

Comment: It's generally better to retain the database table that you have separate, so that you can do queries like "what date did Sylvie have Cake?" (which is harder with the view you're proposing); but to use something like GROUP_CONCAT() when retrieving data to make it seem like the multiple records contain one set of data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for MySQL [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
  SELECT Name, Date, GROUP_CONCAT(Menu) AS Menu
    FROM Table
GROUP BY Name, Date
```

This will give your data like that:

```
|--------|------------|-------------------|
| Name   | Date       | Menu              |
|--------|------------|-------------------|
| Sylvie | 2001-01-01 | Candy,Cake,Cheese |
| Sylvie | 2001-02-01 | Milk,Tea          |
|--------|------------|-------------------|
```

From that you just need to use PHP [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) function to get each menu record as an array.

Comment: You're welcome! I was guessing exactly this when I asked you which database you was using! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to store the value into the database and use [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) or [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) when you get the value from the database.

Comment: I'm looking at it now... thanks for the references.. :) I really need to read more